# validation rule error Incorrect argument type for function 'ISBLANK()'

Tags: formula-field, validation-rule, isblank

IF( ISBLANK( Close_Date__c ) ,
TODAY() - Open_Date__c ,
Close_Date__c - Open_Date__c )

Comment: Is this a [tag:formula-field] or [tag:validation-rule]? It can't be both and make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rule formula expects to return TRUE or FALSE, but I don't see your formula returning any of them. Your formula returns a number, which is difference of two dates.

Comment: If you could please explain, what you are trying to achieve, because I tried in one formula field, and ISBLANK is supported with date fields as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with this [see here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyTzAAK). Can you test with ISNULL
IF( ISNULL( Close_Date__c ) , TODAY() - Open_Date__c , Close_Date__c - Open_Date__c )

Comment: The Known Issue is not related to the OP's question.

Comment: Yes I know I want to make him aware

Answer (score 0):

This is a formula expression is part of your validation rule.

ISBLANK() perfectly works with Date field.

I think you are trying to achieve something which is not clear from your question.